# Jquery validation: 'one table row one form ' does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, tablelayout

my code:

```
<table>
    <form id='editform1'>
    <tr>
        <td><input type.../> </td>
        <td><input type.../> </td>
        <td><input type='submit'/> </td>
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $('#editform1').validate(); </script>
    </form>

    <form id='editform2'>
    <tr>
        <td><input type.../> </td>
        <td><input type.../> </td>
        <td><input type='submit'/> </td>
    </tr>
     <script type="text/javascript"> $('#editform2').validate(); </script>
    </form>

    <form id='editform3'>
    <tr>
        <td><input type.../> </td>
        <td><input type.../> </td>
        <td><input type='submit'/> </td>
    </tr>
     <script type="text/javascript"> $('#editform3').validate(); </script>
    </form>
</table>
```

So when I click submit button, the relevanted row data will pass to background successfully

But the jquery validation is not work!

Though the 'form' tag can not put on 'tr' tag, but in Fixfox and chrome, the data can be submited successfully

so how to make jquery validation works in this situation

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, table can not have form as child element.

Comment: Then how to get my demands  when only using one table tag!

Comment: Why use a table at all ? Is it a requirement ? Couldn't you use display table/table-cell instead if table-like sizing is what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 3):

As already stated, your HTML is invalid.  Only certain tags, like `<tr>`, are allowed as *direct* descendants of `<table>`.

This is exactly why the validate plugin is not working.

All code in the two examples below is *identical*, except for the placement of the `<form>` tags.

---

**Case 1: < Broken by invalid HTML**

Invalid HTML.  The form always passes validation even when there are empty fields.

```
<table>
    <form>
    ...
    </form>
</table>
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/NVHgZ/

---

**Case 2:  <  This one is your solution**

VALID HTML.  Validation plugin is working as expected.

```
<form>
    <table>    
    ...    
    </table>
</form>
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/PXbjN/

---

Since you want to have multiple forms inside of one `<table>`, then you must follow the proper conventions for valid HTML by *nesting* another `table` inside of your `table`.  BTW, "table layouts" are a thing of the past.  Modern designs use CSS and containers like `div` elements for precise content layout.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <form id="one">
                <table>
                ....
                </table>
            </form>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <form id="two">
                <table>
                ....
                </table>
            </form>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <form id="three">
                <table>
                ....
                </table>
            </form>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the reason why I do not using this is that It is very hard to align between the tables in td!  my table  is complicated(some 'clospan' and 'rowspan') and dynamically

Comment: So you are right, the  'div' element is better, but I had to do more works on css to suit my table-theme in my system!

Comment: @mainlove, if your question is how to make jQuery Validate work properly with a table based layout, I've provided you with the only solution.  If you insist on keeping your invalid HTML, then this plugin won't work and you'll eventually have another problem.   Good luck.